# Search and replace the string

Tags: r

I have a variable b

```
  b      
 hit?
 nit
 bit
 kit
 fit
```

I want to search the string "?" in b and if it is available, i want to replace it with "None"

I tried below

```
a<-regexpr("?",b,fixed = TRUE)
if (a >0) {
b = 'none'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use `grep` to get the numeric index of elements in 'b' that have `?`. Then assign those elements to 'none'

```
i1 <- grep("[?]", df1$b)
```

As `?` is a metacharacter, we can either place them inside square brackets or escape it `\\?` or use `fixed = TRUE` i.e.

```
i1 <- grep("?", df1$b, fixed=TRUE)

df1$b[i1] <- "none"
df1
#     b
#1 none
#2  nit
#3  bit
#4  kit
#5  fit
```

---

If we are using `data.table`, this can be done in place

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(df1)[grep("[?]", b), b := "none"]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(b = c("hit?", "nit", "bit", "kit", "fit")), 
.Names = "b", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: I am voting for it since it contains explanations of the answer/code, which I think is always helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use gsub:

```
df$b<-gsub("?", "", df$b)
```